# Openbox: How to show windows from all virtual desktops in Alt+Tab dialog

Tags: openbox

I want to cycle all windows from all virtual desktops when using Alt+Tab in Openbox. At the moment, only windows from the current desktop are shown. Is there a way to configure Openbox so that it shows all windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set 'allDesktops' to 'yes' in your ~/.config/openbox/rc.xml file. Keep a backup of old file.

```
<keybind key="A-Tab">
  <action name="NextWindow">
    <allDesktops>no<allDesktops>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="C-A-Tab">
  <action name="NextWindow">
    <allDesktops>yes<allDesktops>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Comment: Thank you! Don't know how I missed this...